# C# how to disable stacktrace when throwing exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have created a custom exception like bellow

```
public class AppException : Exception
{
    private readonly string _innerStackTrace = "";

    public AppException()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public AppException(string message, string stackTrace)
        : base(message)
    {
        this._innerStackTrace = stackTrace;
    }


    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {
            return this._innerStackTrace;
        }
    }

}
```

When I am throwing this exception and catching it using try catch I am serializing that exception and can see a property StackTraceString which contains full stacktrace of that exception which I don't want. As fetching stacktrace is expensive is there any way to force exception object to not fetch the stacktrace?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Comment: Related: [Custom Exceptions: When should you create them?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2008/10/20/custom-exceptions-when-should-you-create-them/)

Comment: Why are you throwing this exception in the first place? Exceptions are for exceptional situations. If you worry about performance when an exception has been thrown, you either worry about the wrong thing or, more likely, throwing the exception for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @ZoharPeled We are maintaining exceptional cases in our business flow using exception. for this we are creating custom exception for each exceptional case and catching it in the root level and giving proper message to end user. Seems throwing&catching exception is expensive as it need to generate stacktrace. We need to get rid from it.

Comment: @Anup throwing exceptions is expensive *with a debugger attached*; in regular usage, however: you can throw and catch exceptions at a high rate. There *are* scenarios were exception overhead is a real thing, but in general it is **wildly** misunderstood and exaggerated - and almost certainly isn't a problem you have. By a quick test here, throwing and catching an exception including a stack-trace takes about `0.05ms` - slow to a computer, but fast to a human

Comment: @MarcGravell We are developing backend api where there will be huge number of request each second. Do you think throwing exception from business service and catching them from middleware to create proper response is not expensive for this scenario? Like [this](http://www.monitis.com/blog/improving-net-application-performance-part-10-exception-management/) there are lot of pages where throwing exception to control business flow is not recommended.

Comment: @Anup in most cases the cost of an exception is *nothing* compared to your service actually doing something. The main time that an exception would be expensive is if you're doing it in the middle of a tight loop, **and suppressing it** - i.e. so you might actually have 20,000 exceptions in a loop because it fails for every row. Which doesn't sound like what you're doing *at all*.

Comment: We're seeing significant delays coming from exceptions since we have multiple Tasks running simultaneously. We're only interested in the first finished one (with Task.WhenAny) and it's critical that we cancel the remaining ones. This is done with CancellationTokens which cause all remaining Tasks to throw an exception. Based on profiling this allocates plenty of memory and takes several milliseconds which is unacceptable in our use case. Still looking for a solution.